# I want to apply for a tier 4 UK visa but I was previously denied visa to the US, will this affect the UK decision?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, study

I was denied a study visa to the US on the basis that they were not satisfied I had enough family ties to come back to my country, now I want to apply for a UK study visa, will the US rejection affect the UK decision?

Comment: They will certainly be aware of it and look at it, but a US refusal is not necessarily a show-stopper. Are you asking if you should declare it or not? Anyway, please use Expats for T4, we only know about visitors.  http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions thanks